# Wireless not working in Wubi install?

Tags: wireless, broadcom, setup

I just installed Ubuntu with Wubi and it never gave me the screen suggested in the installation steps to connect to the Internet. Now I cannot detect any kind of Internet.

Comment: Did you install it from inside Windows (Wubi Install) or from the LiveCD. If you are in Ubuntu can you type in Dash "Additional Drivers" and see if the Wireless Card Drivers appear?

Comment: I installed from inside windows.
I have tried that, but it tells me there are no proprietary drivers in use; that I need to authenticate the Broadcom STA wireless driver, and then that I need a password that I am not authorized to even attempt to submit.

Comment: There was another question here related to installing from inside Windows and having a Broadcom Wireless card. The solution was to install it from the LiveCD. I myself have a Broadcom also. To be more specific the Broadcom BCM4321. Can you try to install Ubuntu from the LiveCD and see if it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've rebooted after installation, and log in, you'll need to go to the upper right area of your desktop. In the image below, there are several indicator icons, if you'll notice the one that looks like an upside down pie piece. Left click on that to see what networks are available to you. If you don't see a checked option for `Enable Wireless`
You may need to connect your device up to a wired network cable and check for additional drivers as suggested previously. Hope this helps.

Based on your response, here is what I would try and do next as this worked recently when I helped an individual during a LUG meeting.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

You might need to also do:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If you notice any errors in the terminal.

I also believe on his installation that I had to go to additonal drivers once I had updated the firmware, then the driver appeared and let me activate it. It worked, and I had him reboot to verify that it was good to go (which it was!). Let me know how things work out!

[image: Wifi/Ethernet Indicator]

Comment: Thank you, I did not have the check for Enable Wireless, but I restarted the computer and now I do. However, now near the top under Wireless Networks, it says "Firmware Missing". When I am home and can try a wired connection I will, but for now I'd like to try everything I can to get my wireless up and working, thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay please check out my additions above!

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Ubuntu so probably someone already tried it but it worked for me:
I connected a LAN cable first and went to system settings. in there I clicked on software sources and additional drivers. clicked on "using broadcome 802.11 ..." and apply changes.
After that it took few minutes to update and my Wi-Fi was working. 
You have to do it with a cable in otherwise it doesn't work.
Hope that helps and sorry if I'm stating the obvious.
good luck